# JQuery ajax call to WebService with URL stored in web.config file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am calling a WebService (ASP.NET) from a JQuery ajax call - this is working fine. What I want to do though is move the WebService into a different project to the one for the WebApp. I have added a Web Reference to my project but now what I need is to pick up the service URL from the web.config as use that as the URL in my JQuery ajax call. I want to do this so that the application support team can move the WebService to wherever they like and only need to update the web.config and not edit ASPX pages.

What is the best way of doing this? I can get the URL from the web.config file so I just need to know what is the best way of passing it to the jquery ajax call at runtime? So far I have only worked with hardcoded URL's.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the url from the config in `Page_Load` event and then store the url as a HiddenField value, which can be retrieved through jQuery:

ASPX:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="urlHiddenField" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Codebehind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string url = RetrieveUrlFromConfig();
      urlHiddenField.Value = url;
 }
```

Javascript:

```
var serviceUrl = $("#urlHiddenField").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: serviceUrl,
  success: function(msg) { }
});
```

**An alternative solution**, if you dont't want to use a Hidden Field is to register a Startup Script in codebehind, that will assign the url to a global Javascript variable:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "defineUrl", String.Format("_serviceUrl = '{0}';", RetrieveUrlFromConfig()), true);
```

Where `_serviceUrl` is the Javascript variable already defined outside the scope of the function that will make the Ajax request.